# Use Google as an OpenID without logging into the rest of it?

Tags: google-account, openid

Every time I login to Google as my OpenID I stay signed-in. This can get annoying as I feel safer searching Google without being logged-in, even if my dynamic IP is logged.

Obviously I can just immediately go to Google and log-out, but as this is a pain, i'm hoping there's a better way.

I know that unchecking **remember me** would stop it persisting across browser sessions, but I don't want to be logged-in when I next go to Google, whether in the same session or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Cookie Zapper](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/68231) to delete cookies once you leave the tab. Alternatively, if you use a non-US version of Google you can disable cookies on that domain (e.g. using [FireCookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6683/)), however you can't if you don't, as cookies are required on the domain used for OpenID.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the private mode of your browser.  All current browsers have this capability.  In private mode you will not be automatically logged into Google.

Comment: Wouldn't work as i'd want to be logged-into the OpenID-powered site as well.